# Tkinter text shrinks when a button uses pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

For some reason, whenever a button command uses `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`, it shrinks all the text on the window, as well as the window itself. Here's a small snippet to reproduce the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def Plot():
    x = [0,1]
    y = [0,2]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

text = Label(root, text="Testing", font=Font(size=20))
text.pack()

btn = Button(root, text="Click me", command=Plot, font=Font(size=15))
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Any way to avoid this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Shrinks the text on what window?  I ran your code and it seemed fine.  Pressed the button and it opened up a plot window.  I saw no shrinking on the original window (though it was behind the plot window).

Comment: The code worked fine for me on OSX, no change in the size of text after clicking the button.